# Fantasy book with a young male transported to another world; giants and strange sexual themes?

Tags: story-identification, books

This is going to be a tough one. I read this book as a preteen and I distinctly remember it being uncomfortable and inappropriate for my reading age.

It was a fantasy book involving a young male protagonist who is transported to another world (possibly through a portal on a beach). In this world, he encounters a female spirit that becomes sexually involved with him / forces him to fall asleep. When he wakes up the next day, the young man is now a fully grown, strong adult. Other details that I remember include "giants" of some kind as the villains of the book, with reference to women getting ripped apart by having to have sex with the giants and/or give birth to giant children. Also, there was a scene where the protagonist eats the flesh of a female demon to bring her under his control, and a scene where the protagonist is aroused by a statue and jumps into a pool of water to hide it.

I believe the book was written by a male author and had an orange cover. I think it may have been the first in a series.

Comment: Odds of this being a Piers Anthony book?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this (approximate year)?  Hardcover or paperback?  Was it in English?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots No takers, I agree.  Either him or Jack Chalker.

Comment: I don't remember my exact age when I read the book, but the year I read it would have been sometime before 2012 if I had to guess. The book was in English, but I can't guarantee it wasn't a translation. I don't remember whether it was hardcover or paperback.

Comment: semi-duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/167953/book-or-series-with-7-layers-of-worlds-where-each-layers-inhabitants-are-like (about the series as a whole)

Comment: @ZeissIkon Can't be Chalker, OP did not mention any bizarre transformation of a woman.

Answer (score 15):

I thought the description sounded familiar, but after a little searching, I am actually going to suggest a book that I have not personally read.  This seems to match with some descriptions of *The Knight* (2004) by [Gene Wolfe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_Wolfe), the first of two books in *[The Wizard Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_Knight)* series.  Although I have not read either of the two books, the adolescent sexuality angle sounds very characteristic of Wolfe.

I found the suggestion by searching for: `fantasy novel with human-giant sex`.  This led me to this [LibraryThing discussion](https://www.librarything.com/topic/70347#1511469) and then to a description of the book:

> In The Wizard Knight by Gene Wolfe there are two instances:  in the first instance young Ables night with a faire queen is tastefully alluded to and left to the reader to fill in the rest, while in the latter there is a graphic description of what happens when a giant rapes a human woman — and the resulting pregnancy.

Further information, per [LibraryThing](https://www.librarything.com/work/215147):

> THE WIZARD KNIGHT springs from the myths, legends and literature of times past. A teenager passes from Earth to a magical realm of seven worlds, where he is given a hero's adult body and named Able.  Though forced to act as a man, inside he is still a boy, even as he sets off to find his destined sword and become a knight.  In his quest he battles giants, meets gods, heroes and a sorceress (who repeatedly tries to seduce him), and serves the mercurial dragon king Arnthor in a was [sic.] that could end everything.

The two books (*The Knight* and *The Wizard*) have been released both singly and together.  These seem to be the most common covers.

[image: The Knight]

[image: The Wizard Knight]

Comment: I can't figure out how to comment after making an account (given that I made this question as a guest), but "The Knight" by Gene Wolfe is the book! Thank you so much to Buzz for freeing me of the curse of this book - it's been haunting me for over a decade now.

Comment: @Kat Since you created a second account to comment, please follow the instructions on [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to **merge** your two accounts - you'll then be able to access the original account and *accept* this answer to mark it as correct.